# DataGridView column sorting is working but not sorting in correct order

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DGV which is bound to a datatable which is populated via below code:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = FetchMyDataTable(SQLQuery, ConnectionString)
Me.DataSet.Table.Rows.Clear()
For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
Dim cost As Double = dr("cost")
```

All values are saved to a variable then the variables are assigned straight to the field in the datatable or used in a calculation which is wrapped as CDbl():

```
Dim rw As DataRow = Me.DataSet.Table.NewRow
rw("cost") = cost
```

or

```
rw("nett") = CDbl(Math.Round((cost + varaiable1 + varaiable2) * (1 + (varaiable3/ 100)), 2))
```

Fields in the DGV require the correct sign after the value and it is either a % or £:

```
rw("cost") = "£ " & rw("cost")
```

or

```
rw("profit") = rw("profit") & " %"
```

I have two methods where one adds the sign to all values in the DGV and another that removes. I execute RemoveSigns() before I do any recalculations after user changes a value in DGV and after I do AddSigns().

Now the fields in the DGV are DataGridViewAutoFilterTextBoxColumn Column Types, whether that affects anything unsure, but when I try sorting one of the columns they do not sort propery, e.g. value £ 8.40 will be above £ 90.20 and then below will be £ -12.00.
I need it so it will sort so that if ascending then negatives first and then value going up and if descending then highest value and ending on negatives.

EDIT: I believe it might be because the DataSet.Table to which the DGV is bound has the columns configured to Strings and not Doubles. When I update those to be Doubles then I am unable to add the £ and % sign to the fields. Is there any other way of achieving what I am after here?

Comment: You don't have to add symbols, you need Double (or Decimal) Fields and use the `DataGridView.CellFormatting` event to format the output as you like. You can also use the `[DataGridViewTextBoxColumn].Format` property. What's important is that your data is stored in the correct format. The *presentation* (the values rendered in a UI) can be handled when needed, based on a User requirements (a User may expect `$` or `€` instead of `£`, for example, so you also need currency conversion tools. These won't of course operate on formatted strings). Also, sort the data, not the Control.

Comment: As Jimi said, the property you bind to should be a double, then simply set the column `Format = "C"` or `"C2"` if you want to force it to two decimal places instead of relying on the system setting. See [Standard numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings).

Comment: Thank you both - the formatting to C2 seems to be working on the fields displaying 'money'. In terms of displaying percentages, the values displayed in the fields already are worked out percentage values and all they need is the % sign. I see that the "P" format multiples the value by 100 and then displays as a percentage according to the Standard numeric format strings - is there any way of omitting that?

Comment: @Jimi your suggestion has allowed me to fix the issue I was occuring. Do you want to post it as an answer so I can mark it as the resolution to the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment by @Jimi proved to be solution to the issue -

> You don't have to add symbols, you need Double (or Decimal) Fields and use the DataGridView.CellFormatting event to format the output as you like. You can also use the [DataGridViewTextBoxColumn].Format property. What's important is that your data is stored in the correct format. The presentation (the values rendered in a UI) can be handled when needed, based on a User requirements (a User may expect $ or € instead of £, for example, so you also need currency conversion tools. These won't of course operate on formatted strings). Also, sort the data, not the Control.